# Criterion for triviality of monodromy in smooth families

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, hodge-theory, monodromy, hodge-structure

Let $\pi: X \to \Delta^*$ be a smooth, projective morphism. We know that for each $k$, there is a natural local system  $L:=R^k \pi_*\mathbb{C}$. The associated vector bundle $\mathcal{L}:=L \otimes \mathcal{O}_{\Delta^*}$ is equipped with a Gauss-Manin connection $\nabla$. Using the Griffiths transversality, we know that for every $s \in \Delta^*$, the Gauss-Manin connection induces a morphism $$\overline{\nabla}_s : H^{p,k-p}(X_s) \to H^{p-1,k-p+1}(X_s) \otimes \Omega^1_{\Delta^*,s}$$

My question is as follows: Fix $k$ as above.
Suppose for every $p \ge 0$, $s \in \Delta^*$ and $\gamma_s \in H^{p,q}(X_s)$, we have $\overline{\nabla}_s(\gamma_s)=0$. Does it imply that the corresponding monodromy representation (associated to the local system $L$) is trivial i.e., the monodromy representation from $\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathrm{Aut}(H^k(X_s,\mathbb{C}))$ maps $1$ to the identity element?

I am mainly interested in the case when $k=3$ and every fiber is rationally connected. Any idea/reference will be most welcome.

Comment: Your condition implies that the Hodge structure is constant. This does not imply that the monodromy is trivial, but if your family is the restriction of an algebraic family over an algebraic curve then the monodromy would be finite.

Comment: @naf You can assume that the family is the restriction of an algebraic family over an algebraic curve. I am perhaps wrong, but I thought since the monodromy representation is indecomposable, constancy of Hodge structures will imply triviality of monodromy. Also, I understand the vanishing of $\overline{\nabla}$ implies that infinitesimally the Hodge structure is constant, how do I show it over the entire puntured disc?

Comment: The vanishing of $\overline{\nabla}$ means that the differential of the period map is $0$ at all points in the punctured disc, so the period map must be constant. It is easy to construct an isotrivial family of elliptic curves with non-trivial monodromy. If you embed such a family in $\mathbb{P}^3$ (times the base) and then blow it up, you will get a family of rationally connected varieties with non-trivial monodromy on $H^3$.

Comment: @naf: Thank you. Sounds like a very good answer. Why don't you write this as an answer?

Comment: @naf Is there any criterion of checking trivial monodromy using Period map? Is there any literature which studies similar questions?

Comment: I think it is very unlikely that the period map can be used to determine whether the monodromy is trivial, rather than just finite.